# setPage magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta, pagination

i want use pagination for my module. I have code

```
return $this->_faqFactory->create()->getCollection()->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage())->setPageSize(10);
```

**Edited**
in view page1 
[image]

And page 2
[image]

result same? what wrong? any thank.

Comment: code seem to right...please check collection is give the data or not. or put  1  instead of $this->getCurrentPage()

Comment: both have data. but in view page1 and page 2 result same.

Comment: any suggestion?

Comment: code should be like this where $page_number is the param from url
return $this->_faqFactory->create()->getCollection()->setCurPage($page_number)->setPageSize(10);

Comment: side note, setCurPage() has to be before setPageSize()

Answer (score 1):

call function in block file.

```
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $collection = $this->_faqFactory->create()->getCollection();

        parent::_prepareLayout();
        if ($collection) {
            // create pager block for collection
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager','my.custom.pager');
            // // assign collection to pager
            $pager->setLimit(10)->setCollection($collection);
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);// set pager block in layout
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    // method for get pager html
    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }
```

call method in phtml file below.

```
    <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
        <div class="toolbar bottom"><?php echo $block->getPagerHtml(); ?></div>
    <?php endif ?>
```